# unable to copy to system clipboard with +clipboard and +xterm_clipboard in vimx

Tags: register, os-clipboard

The system is Centos7.2. I have installed vim-enhanced and vim-X11, used `vimx` command.

It shows that vimx supports `clipboard` and `xterm_clipboard`. But in vimx, there is no `reg +` and `reg *`. I can't copy text to system clipboard using command `"+yy`

[image: supporting clipboard and xterm_clipboard]
[image: there is no register + and *]

Comment: Removed tag `gvim`. Vim needs to connect to the X server to be able to interact with the system clipboard. Might be that Vim is somehow not able to connect to X. Are you able to start any X application from your terminal (like xterm or xclock)? Are you able to do that from inside Vim (like: `:!xterm`)?

Comment: BTW: If `echo v:windowid` prints `0` (zero), Vim is _not_ connected to X.

Comment: @Ralf I connect to a Linux server using secureCRT, and run the command `vimx` in command-line mode. Command `echo v:windowid` in vimx prints `0`. There is no command `xterm` or `xclock` on the remote server. Thanks, I will search 'X server' for help.

Answer (score 1):

On GNOME terminal use shift + mouseleft + drag to select. Ctrl + Shift + C to copy. Ctrl + Shift + V to Paste.

Comment: Well, that technically transfers the responsibility to Gnome... but the user may be using another DE, or maybe he wants to include `"+yy` in a function/macro/whatever.

Comment: "+yy is not working in debian or ubuntu's gnome terminal. That's why.